# Connect to gRPC service via Kubernetes API server proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, kubernetes-apiserver

Let's say we have a Kubernetes service which serves both a RESTful HTTP API and a gRPC API:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: myservice
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    name: grpc
```

We want to be able to reach those service endpoints externally, for example from another Kubernetes cluster.

This could be achieved by changing the service type from `ClusterIP` to `LoadBalancer`. However, let's assume that this is not desirable, for example because it requires additional public IP addresses.

An alternative approach would be to use the [apiserver proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/proxies) which

> connects a user outside of the cluster to cluster IPs which otherwise might not be reachable

This works with the http endpoint. For example, if the http API exposes an endpoint `/api/foo`, it can be reached like this:

```
http://myapiserver/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/myservice:http/proxy/api/foo
```

Is it somehow possible to also reach the gRPC service via the apiserver proxy? It would seem that since gRPC uses HTTP/2, the apiserver proxy won't support it out of the box. e.g. doing something like this on the client side...

```
grpc.Dial("myapiserver/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/myservice:grpc/proxy")
```

... won't work.

Is there a way to connect to a gRPC service via the apiserver proxy?

If not, is there a different way to connect to the gRPC service from external, without using a `LoadBalancer` service?

Comment: instead of api proxy, you should linkerd multi-cluster communication approach, https://linkerd.io/2.11/features/multicluster/ and its pretty easy to mirror or expose service

Comment: Appreciate your comment @Adiii. Unfortunately, Linkerd multicluster sets up a LoadBalancer service for its gateway, which requires a separate public IP - that's what I'm hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

`...not to require an additional public IP`

NodePort is not bound to public IP. That is, your worker node can sits in the private network and reachable at the node private IP:nodePort#. The meantime, you can use `kubectl port-forward --namespace mynamespace service myservice 8080:8080` and connect thru localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NodePort` service. Each of your k8s workers will start listening on some high port. You can connect to any of the workers and your traffic would be routed to the target service.

`apiserver-proxy` solution looks like workaround to me and is far from production grade solution. You shouldn't route the traffic to your services through k8s API servers (even though it's technically possible). Control plane should be doing just control plane things and not data plane (traffic routing, running workloads, ...)

`LoadBalancer` service can be typically configured to create Internal LB (with internal IP from your VPC) instead External LB. This frankly the only 'correct' solution.

Comment: I understand your concern. For the scenario I have in mind, it would be hugely beneficial not to require an additional public IP, hence my interest in routing through a small amount of traffic through API server's proxy.

Comment: Probably depends on what reasoning is behind not requiring additional public IP but on AWS or GCP if it's security or cost it's perfectly possible to create internal load balancer with internal IP - not public. 

If you don't want to spend money for load balancer itself I'm afraid general pattern in all k8s providers is load balancer per k8s service.

Comment: Alternative to apiserver proxy would be kubectl port forwarding. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/ Disadvantage is you can't port-forward to service itself. Only to target pod. You can run port-forward in screen or even as systemd unit on background. Port forwarding is on L4 so it doesn't matter what application layer protocol you send through it.